# ActionLink создает неправильную ссылку

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

```
if (rol == 1)
{
    @Html.ActionLink("Личный кабинет", "MainPanel", "Admin", new {@class="polosaSleva"})
}
```

Есть 2 контроллера Teacher и Admin. В одном из методом первого контроллера я создаю ссылку на представление второго. (Код сверху).
В итоге, создается ссылка на представление MainPanel контроллера Teacher а не Admin. Не могу понять в чем проблема.

Answer (score 3):

В вашем случае имя контроллера воспринималось как объект маршрута:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

```
@Html.ActionLink(
    linkText : "Личный кабинет", 
    actionName : "MainPanel", 
    controllerName : "Admin", 
    routeValues : null, 
    htmlAttributes : new { @class = "polosaSleva" }
)
```

Comment: Все работает. Спасибо! А в чем ошибка? Я всегда делал ActionLink без routeValues и работало все нормально.

Comment: @Vivus вы, видимо, делали ActionLink на действие внутри контроллера, а перегрузка этого метода для действия в другом контроллере требует параметра routeValues четвертым по счету. @Html.ActionLink("Личный кабинет", "MainPanel", "Admin", null, new {@class="polosaSleva"})